# Lua problem with variables being referenced

Tags: lua, reference

I have this in main.lua:

```
local Vector3 = require "vector3"

local A = {
    v = Vector3:new(16,16,16)
}

b = Vector3:new(A.v.x + 2, A.v.y + 3, A.v.z + 4)
print(A.v.x)
```

and this in Vector3.lua

```
local Vector3 = {
    x,
    y,
    z
}

function Vector3:new(x,y,z)
    o = {}
    setmetatable(o,self)
    self.__index = self

    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.z = z

    return o
end

return Vector3
```

Why does it print 18 instead of 16? I guess it has something to do with the variables being referenced. How can I get 16 as result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector3:new` is setting fields in `Vector3`, not in the object created. Try this:

```
function Vector3:new(x,y,z)
    local o = {}
    setmetatable(o,self)
    self.__index = self
    o.x = x
    o.y = y
    o.z = z
    return o
end
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Is is necessary to add "local" in front of "o"?

Comment: @float, it is not necessary, but otherwise you're creating a global variable.

Comment: @float as you want to get a new vector instance every time you call Vector3:new() it is quite actually quite necessary. try to create a second vector with and without local and you'll see the difference